# How to make one cart rule like 1 Shirt =Rs.1900 , 2 Shirt =Rs.3200 , 3 Shirt =Rs.4400 in magento-2.2?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.7

Original Price of shirt is different like Rs.3199 ,Rs.3799,Rs.2999.
I want to make a cart price rule with following conditions:
If cart having 1 shirt it will give in Rs.1900
1 Shirt =Rs.1900 , 
2 Shirt =Rs.3200 , 
3 Shirt =Rs.4400
How can make it that type of rule in magento-2.2?

Comment: 1900, 3200 and 4400 apples? pears? moneys?

Comment: its product price. @PhilippSander

Comment: anybody help me

Comment: show us the cart price rule you are currently using. if you don't have one create it and we can help you solve the problems. we are not a coding service

Comment: I'd say Tier-Prices is also a good approach to solve this

Comment: you also have to define whats the price-rule for more than 3 OR limit the amount of this product in the cart to 3

Comment: I didn't know , how to make that type of rule. In Magento- 2.2.7, We gave discount Percentage of discount, Fixed Amount of discount and Fixed amount on whole cart. There is no rule for specific condition.

Comment: this is a common use case. please search for a tutorial on how to solve this.

Comment: There is no default rule in magento-2.2.7 for this use case

Comment: some 3rd party extension should do this. Search for such extension

Comment: you don't need a third party extension to solve this! you just need to configure either a cart price rule or tierprices. but OP has to at least try something and provide us what was tried